# ng-repeat convert resource objects to simple objects

Tags: angularjs

Iam getting my data with help of the Angular's $resource service as array. Each element of that array is an Resource-Object. So i can use methods like $save and $update of these Objects. In a view i represent my array with the help of the ng-repeat directive like:

```
<div ng-repeat="appointment in object.appointments" ng-click="editAppointment(appointment)">
```

And here i get in trouble. The appointment-Object i get in the editAppointment-Method is a simple Object. No Resource Object anymore. So i cant use the helpfull methods like i mentioned above.

```
$scope.editAppointment= function(appointment){
    console.log(appointment); // > Object
    console.log(object.appointments); // > Array of Resource           
}
```

Have somebody noticed that problem too? May its a bug, but i cant imagine that.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your resource class is called Appointment, you should just be able to do:

```
$scope.editAppointment= function(appointment){
   new Appointment(appointment).save();         
}
```

Presumably your Appointment resource looks something like the following (i.e. it correctly maps some sort of id property from existing objects to the URL parameters):

```
var Appointment = $resource('/appointment/:appointmentId', {appointmentId:'@id'});
```

This would be the case if your appointment objects (i.e. the underlying JSON objects handled by your API) have an ID property called `id`. If it's called something else (or if there are multiple path variables in your URL) you'll just need to change the second argument to map all of the properties of the objects being saved (the values starting with '@') to the URL path variables (the things starting with ':' in your URL).

See where they save a new card in the credit card example here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource. The fact that they're dealing with a totally new object and that you're trying to save an existing one is irrelevant. Angular doesn't know the difference.

Comment: thats ofc a solution. But i wonder why i have to create a new Resource Object, because i already have one in the array. Only after the ng-repeat directive iterate over that array all Resource Objects are converter to normal Objects. And the questions here is, is that a bug?